# Use [Other] Geometry as Particle System Emitter Shape

Tags: scenekit, particles, particle-system

In SceneKit Particle Systems there's an option to use [Other] as a shape for the emittance of particles.

How do I assign something to this property in the Editor?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in the editor, only programmatically. This menu item is there so that the correct value can be displayed if the scene was created programmatically and then exported.

Comment: So I create the scene programmatically, with the custom geometry as the emitter shape... then export it, then import it somehow as a .scn file?

Comment: you can export it directly as a .scn file using NSKeyedArchiver

Comment: Argh, got it. Then drag it back into the project, and somehow the Scene Editor scours the .scn file to find the custom emitter shape?

Comment: yes, the editor should display "Other" and use your own geometry. As saved in the .scn file.

Comment: And I can use imported geometry from (e.g.) 3ds Max that's come in as a COLLADA file? For this example, imagine I'm building in the Scene Editor, brought in my COLLADA geometry, and in the .scn editor it's there, then programmatically set the custom geometry as emitter shape... then export this .scn using NSKeyedArchiver, then bring it back in as a .scn file and continue editing the particle values?

Comment: should work. There's no magic in the editor or the file it writes to the disk. It's just an archived scene.

Comment: Has this process changed at all in the last two years? Or I was thinking about getting it "close" to what it is supposed to look like in the editor, and then just copying all those values to create a particle system programmatically with a custom shape. On a side note: One of the huge downsides to Scenekit vs Unity is the total lack of examples for all but the most basic things.